# Overlapping Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, interpolation, irreducible-polynomials

This question is related to this:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412564/interpolating-polynomial-its-root

We have $P_3=P_2\cdot P_1$,for three non-zero polynomials. The degree of each polynomial is at least 1.

Question: Does $P_1$ overlap $P_3$ over more than one point?

---

By overlap I do not mean intersect. Instead, I mean a part of the polynomials can lay on each other over more than one point.
edit: $P_1\neq P_2$

Comment: @JessicaK Thank you; I've edited the question.

Comment: Consider what happens if you subtract the two "overlapping" polynomials. Unless the result is the zero polynomial, this violates the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If two polynomials agree on any open interval (which seems to be what you mean by "lay on each other over more than one point"), then they are identical polynomials.

So the answer to your question is "no", because $deg(P_3) \ge 1 + deg(P_2)$, hence $P_3$ cannot be a constant multiple of $P_1$.

Why must the two polynomials be equal?

Consider points $x = x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n$, where $n$ is the higher of the degrees of the two polynomials, and the $x_i$ are distinct and lie in the shared interval.

If you plug these into both polynomials, you get 
$$
p_1(x_0) = p_3(x_0)\\
p_1(x_1) = p_3(x_1) \\
\ldots \\
p_1(x_n) = p_3(x_n)
$$
which gives you $n$ linear equations in the numbers $c_i = a_i - b_i$, where the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are the coefficients of the two polynomials. These can be written in matrix form as 
$$
V \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ \ldots \\ c_n \end{bmatrix} = 0,
$$
where $V$ is a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix), whose determinant is known to be nonzero, so we can conclude that all $c_i$ are zero, so that the coefficients of the two polynomials are identical.

Comment: Absolutely not. I answered your earlier question on essentially the same topic, which turned out to be a waste of my time because someone else had already answered your *previous* question, which was essentially identical. How 'bout **you** spend some time trying to make sense of our reasonably clear answers?

Comment: Thank you very much. By the way I'm PhD student and trying to learn not wasting any ones time. Some misunderstanding can always happen but it's not exactly the way you see. Thank you again.

Comment: "If two polynomials agree on any open interval then they are identical polynomials." does this apply to two unrelated polynomials ? For instance, if one polynomial is of degree 2 and the other has degree 50, then they do not agree on any open interval?

Comment: Look at the proof above. There is no place in the proof where I assume that the degrees are equal. In fact, I wrote "...where $n$ is the **higher** of the degrees of the two polynomials...". ("max" would have been better.) In other words, *my answer already answers your question.* I suggest you work with your advisor to be sure you know how to construct a proof, read a proof, and understand the statements of theorems in your field. A rigorous course in elementary linear algebra -- up through, say, the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem -- might provide both proof-practice and foundations for your area.

Comment: BTW, you might find it a useful exercise to carefully prove the statement I made via Bezout's Theorem.

Comment: I don't understand why I cannot use your answer above for the following question to say it is impossible:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412856/specific-root-of-interpolating-polynomial/1412898#1412898

Comment: Well...my answer (and your question, at least as I read it) depended on the polynomials being over $\mathbb R$ rather than a finite field. So it won't apply directly. But perhaps the same statement is true (suitably phrased) for finite fields; you might want to try to both state it and prove it via @Guesswhoitis's remark, and then apply THAT to the related question.

Comment: Thanks. Just to confirm it with you. If I define the polynomials over a field and all the values above are defined over the field. Then the answer you provided is still valid. Am I right?

Comment: The notion of "shared interval" is meaningless, so you need to rework that parts. Also, have you confirmed that the vandermonde determinant is still nonzero in the finite field? At this point, MSE is saying "move this to chat," and I'm not gonna do that, so I'm done. Best of luck. DO talk with your advisor!