# Can Two Different Polynomials Agree on an open interval?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

**Question**: For a high degree polynomial $P_1$ , can we have another polynomial $P_2$ that is a part of $P_1$ (or they agree on open interval)?

---

TBN: This question is partially answered in :[Overlapping Polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412610/overlapping-polynomials) however I need to know if it is true for all polynomials of any degree.

Comment: The two first lines in the accepted answer to your earlier question constitute a full and complete answer to this one too.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I mentioned in the question it's related. Also they are not identical. Read them  more carefully please.

Comment: x @user. It's you who need to read the answers you receive more carefully before you repeat questions for which the **very first sentence** in the answer you **already got** constitutes a **full and unambiguous answer**.

Comment: $P_1 - P_2$ is a polynomial, so it has only finitely many roots (no more than its degree). If you had $P_1 = P_2$ on an open interval, then $P_1 -P_2$ would have infinitely many (uncountably many, even) roots, so this is impossible.

Comment: Not only does it hold for polynomials of all degrees as already covered in your earlier question, it's true for all real analytic functions. Check https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem for an even more general case.

Comment: It is true for polynomial *functions* as others say.  However polynomial curves may be distinct yet have portions that overlap/coincide "on an interval".  The Question lacks enough specificity to claim you have asked something different from the earlier post (proposed as a duplicate).

Comment: @hardmath Could you please give your idea about this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412564/interpolating-polynomial-its-root

Comment: @Macavity Would the situation would be the same if the polynomials are defined over a finite field?

Comment: @user13676: You have deleted the other Question you asked me to share thoughts about.  Over an infinite field (of any characteristic) two univariate polynomials are equal *as polynomials* if and only if they are equal *as functions* on the given field (i.e. evaluation of the polynomials at field elements).  This fails for a finite field (since there are infinitely many polynomials but only finitely many functions from the field to itself).

Comment: @hardmath Yes, here is the question. I would much appreciate if you give me a clue.   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412856/specific-root-of-interpolating-polynomial

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Assume that $P_1$ and $P_2$ are equal on some open interval and let the degrees of $P_1$ and $P_2$ be at most $n$. Then $P_1 - P_2$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$ that has at least $n + 1$ distinct roots [since every number in the interval is a root]. But a nonzero polynomial of degree at most $n$ has at most $n$ roots.

Comment: Thak you for the answers.

Comment: Can this be used to answer NO to this question? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412564/interpolating-polynomial-its-root/1412637#1412637

Answer (score 1):

Only if $P_1=P_2$ and that holds for any degrees

Comment: What if we define the polynomials over a finite field? would the situation be the same?

Comment: It depends on the number of points in the field, if the number is greater than the degree of the highest polynomial at least by 1, then the result is still valid, otherwise it fails

Comment: thank you for the answer. Can I have your idea about this question please.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412856/specific-root-of-interpolating-polynomial?noredirect=1#comment2880358_1412856